# Java: Communicating with a command line application

Tags: java, macos, io, terminal, communication

I want to program a chess GUI in Java. The user can enter a move and then I want the program to make a move. Therefore I'll use an UCI (Universal Chess Interface). An UCI is a terminal/command line application (I'm using Mac OS X and Terminal) that calculates the best move in a position. Now what I need to do is write and read to this terminal application.

For example:
I want the best move for a certain position, so I type:
"`go`" (calculates the best move)

Let's say I get this answer:
"`e2e4`" (means moving the Pawn (that's a piece in chess) from the e2-square to the e4-square)

Now I need to read that "e2e4" and then ask the user for his next move. So i kinda need to loop through these steps all the time until there is a checkmate:
1. Ask for a move
2. Calculate best response

I've already seen a lot of other StackOverflow questions asking the same question: How to run a command and get its output in Command Line/Terminal. But all answers only use one command, as for instance `runtime.exec("ls");` But that's only one command. What I want is to enter a command, get the response, execute another command and so on, so basically I need to communicate with Mac OSX' Terminal app (alternating input and output). How do I accomplish that in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Just look up the return type of Runtime.exec(). It returns a [java.lang.Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

It offers two methods for input and output streaming: [getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and getInputStream()

You can read and write to the opened Process for ex. with BufferedReaders / BufferedWriters.

For Example: (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745245/2358582)

```
import java.io.*;

public class c {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd");
        BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

        //communication
        setUpStreamGobbler(p.getInputStream(), System.out);
        out.write("cmd\n");
        out.flush();
    }

    public static void setUpStreamGobbler(final InputStream is, final PrintStream ps) {
        final InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        ps.println("process stream: " + line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
process stream: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
process stream: Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalte
n.
process stream:
process stream: P:\Java\ExcecuteFile>cmd
process stream: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
process stream: Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalte
n.
process stream:
```

Comment: This does not work, an Intellij IDEA marks this error: Error:(16, 30) java: no suitable constructor found for BufferedReader(java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    constructor java.io.BufferedReader.BufferedReader(java.io.Reader) is not applicable
      (actual argument java.io.OutputStreamWriter cannot be converted to java.io.Reader by method invocation conversion)
    constructor java.io.BufferedReader.BufferedReader(java.io.Reader,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: I found the error: should be BufferedWriter in the code

Comment: Now all is working fine, how do I output the result to the console? (using System.out.println()?)

Comment: Always try to think before post :) Yes you can output it with System.out.println(buf);

Comment: No, but it is not working, the out.write("command") is not executed

Comment: try flushing the stream.

Comment: no, the `out.write("go")`'s result is not printed when calling `System.out.println(buffer);`

Answer (score 1):

You could execute the command that runs the chess program, and then check the command's output for the best move (using a `Process`).

For example:

```
String move = null;
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("go");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getOutputStream()));
move = reader.readLine();
// 'move'  now holds a reference to the chess program's output, or null if there was none.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this question might help you:
 [I asked something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992518/creating-commands-for-a-terminal-app-in-java),
I hope that this will answer your question